# What does Playmaker mean when he says "Arrowheads confirmed!"?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Whenever Playmaker performs a Link Summon in *Yu-Gi-Oh VRAINS*, he starts by saying

> アローヘッド確認！！！
>   Arrowheads confirmed!

What does that mean? I know that some characters in the *Yu-Gi-Oh* series have their own catchphrases they sometimes say during special kinds of summons, but what is the meaning behind this one specifically? Does it have something to do with confirming summoning conditions? What does the "arrowhead" have to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of arrow heads on a Link Monster corresponds to its link number, so I've always taken this as a declaration that Playmaker is about to perform a Link Summon and that he has the correct materials to do so. Other characters use the phrase as well. From what I've seen of VRAINS, Playmaker sometimes follows the "arrowheads confirmed" statement by saying what link materials he needs.

It is like in Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal and onwards, how some characters when performing an Xyz Summon will say "I'll overlay level X monster1 and monster2 to build the overlay network". It could just be for our clarification and the duellists.